# javafx tableview is not populating

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml

My JavaFX table view is not showing test data:

[main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFkXY.png)

main code:

```
package javafxapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = 
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/FXMLCatalogo.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Controller's code:

```
package javafxapp.controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafxapp.model.Contato;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class FXMLCatalogoController implements Initializable {

    private final ObservableList<Contato> contatos =             
        FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private Label labelNome, labelSobrenome, labelCidade, 
        labelEstado, labelCep, labelDataNasc;

@FXML
private TableView<Contato> tableContato = new TableView<>();

@FXML
private TableColumn<Contato, String> columnNome = new TableColumn<>("Nome");
private TableColumn<Contato, String> columnSobrenome = new TableColumn<>("Sobrenome");

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    columnNome.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nomeProperty());
    columnSobrenome.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().sobrenomeProperty());
    tableContato.setItems(getItems());
    tableContato.getColumns().addAll(columnNome, columnSobrenome);
}    

public ObservableList<Contato> getItems() {
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 1", "Rosa", "São Paulo", "SP", "08285140", "22/08/1990"));
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 2", "Rosa", "Rio Janeiro", "RJ", "08285140", "22/08/1991"));
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 3", "Rosa", "Belo Horizont", "MG", "08285140", "22/08/1992"));
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 4", "Rosa", "São Caetano do Sul", "SP", "08285140", "22/08/1993"));
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 5", "Rosa", "Diadema", "SP", "08285140", "22/08/1994"));
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 6", "Rosa", "Osasco", "SP", "08285140", "22/08/1994"));
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 7", "Rosa", "Guarulhos", "SP", "08285140", "22/08/1995"));
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 8", "Rosa", "São Paulo", "SP", "08285140", "22/08/1996"));
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 9", "Rosa", "São Paulo", "SP", "08285140", "22/08/1997"));
    contatos.add(new Contato("Henrique 10", "Rosa", "São Paulo", "SP", "08285140", "22/08/1998"));
    return contatos;
}

}
```

ps: In debugging is possible do to see that the contatos list correctly filled!

Contato Model Class:

```
package javafxapp.model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;


public class Contato {

private final StringProperty nome;
private final StringProperty sobrenome;
private final StringProperty cidade;
private final StringProperty estado;
private final StringProperty cep;
private final StringProperty dtNasc;

public Contato(String nome, String sobrenome, String cidade, String estado, String cep, String dtNasc) {
    this.nome = new SimpleStringProperty(nome);
    this.sobrenome = new SimpleStringProperty(sobrenome);
    this.cidade = new SimpleStringProperty(cidade);
    this.estado = new SimpleStringProperty(estado);
    this.cep = new SimpleStringProperty(cep);
    this.dtNasc = new SimpleStringProperty(dtNasc);
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome.get();
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome.set(nome);
}

public StringProperty nomeProperty() {
    return this.nome;
}

public String getSobrenome() {
    return sobrenome.get();
}

public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
    this.sobrenome.set(sobrenome);
}

public StringProperty sobrenomeProperty() {
    return this.sobrenome;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return cidade.get();
}

public void setCidade(String cidade) {
    this.cidade.set(cidade);
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado.get();
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado.set(estado);
}

public String getCep() {
    return cep.get();
}

public void setCep(String cep) {
    this.cep.set(cep);
}

public String getDtNasc() {
    return dtNasc.get();
}

public void setDtNasc(String dtNasc) {
    this.dtNasc.set(dtNasc);
}
}
```

My FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="639.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="javafxapp.controller.FXMLCatalogoController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5100334448160535" layoutX="-3.0" 
prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="647.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" 
AnchorPane.leftAnchor="-3.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-5.0" 
AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="298.0" 
prefWidth="322.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tabelaContato" editable="true" 
layoutX="-14.0" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="336.0" 
tableMenuButtonVisible="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" 
AnchorPane.leftAnchor="-14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" 
AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="columnNome" prefWidth="75.0" 
text="Nome" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="columnSobrenome" prefWidth="75.0" 
text="Sobrenome" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" 
/>
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="298.0" 
prefWidth="251.0">
               <children>
              <Label layoutX="24.0" layoutY="-7.0" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="162.0" text="Person Details" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="18.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <GridPane layoutX="30.0" layoutY="48.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
                 <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                 </columnConstraints>
                 <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="25.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="25.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="25.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="25.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="25.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="25.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                 </rowConstraints>
                 <children>
                    <Label text="Nome:" />
                    <Label text="Sobrenome:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                    <Label text="Cidade:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                    <Label text="Estado:" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                    <Label text="CEP:" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                    <Label text="Data Nasc.:" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                    <Label fx:id="labelNome" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                    <Label fx:id="labelSobrenome" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                    <Label fx:id="labelCidade" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                    <Label fx:id="labelEstado" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                    <Label fx:id="labelCep" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                    <Label fx:id="labelDataNasc" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                 </children>
              </GridPane>
                <Button layoutX="22.0" layoutY="259.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Novo" />
                <Button layoutX="133.0" layoutY="259.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Editar" />
                <Button layoutX="225.0" layoutY="259.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Remover" />
              </children></AnchorPane>
    </items>
  </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Questions: 
1. Is needed to add some information about the Observable list in the FXML file?
2. Is needed to make ObservableLsit final?
3. Only adding the list in the Tableview is made the link betwen the list and the tableview?

Because I tryed all this and nothing has changed... :[

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is the `Contato` class?

Comment: Sorry, missed it. My bad.

Comment: a) Don't initialize fields that are intiaitlized from the fxml in the controller code and don't add those your colums to the columns list, if your fxml does this already. b) Annotate all fields that are supposed to be injected with `@FXML` assuming they are non-`public`. c) fix that type `tabelaContato`/`tableContato`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the following elements declared in the `FXML` file

```
<TableView fx:id="tableContato" ... >
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnNome" ... />
        <TableColumn fx:id="columnSobrenome" ... />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

then the manual creation of their instances is wrong. It is only necessary to declare the elements (with the relevant annotation)

```
...
@FXML
private TableView<Contato> tableContato;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Contato, String> columnNome;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Contato, String> columnSobrenome;
...
```

Consequently, the obvious addition of the columns at initialization should be removed

```
...
//tableContato.getColumns().addAll(columnNome, columnSobrenome);
...
```

The above changes should work

In the `FXML` file the table is id `tabelaContato`, and in the controller you use `tableContato`. The same name should be used in both places.

Comment: It has an error in the fxml too tabelaContato(fxml) / tableContato(Controller). Many thanks!